# How to add various SQL columns in the same dropdownlist ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, dropdown

For example, the database has these columns:

```
Name   Type   Place
```

I am already showing all the names in a dropdownlist; how can I show all three columns - Name, Type, Place - in that same dropdown?

This is what I got

```
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">Name:</td>
    <td align="left" colspan="3" style="height: 21px" valign="top">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropD_Name" runat="server" 
         BackColor="White" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
         DataSourceID="SqlDS_Name" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" 
         ForeColor="Black" 
         SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Name") %>' Width="290px">
        <Items>
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        </Items>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
</tr>
```

SqlDS_Name:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDS_Name" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BlablablaConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT Name, Type, Place FROM dbo.vwnames">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks for your help
finally this is the solution for the query

```
SELECT CONCAT (Name,' - ',Type,' - ',Place) AS TextColumn,Name AS NameInfo FROM dbo.vwnames
```

Comment: Standard dropdowns are not built with this functionality. You need a GridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, Type, Place FROM dbo.vwnames
```

Change to :

```
SELECT Name + ',' + Type + ',' + Place AS TextColumn,Name FROM dbo.vwnames
```

result :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDS_Name" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BlablablaConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT Name + ',' + Type + ',' + Place AS TextColumn,Name FROM dbo.vwnames">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And `DropDownList` change to :

```
<asp:DropDownList 
   ID="DropD_Name"
   runat="server" 
   BackColor="White" 
   AppendDataBoundItems="true"
   DataSourceID="SqlDS_Name" 
   DataTextField="TextColumn" 
   DataValueField="Name" 
   ForeColor="Black" 
   SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Name") %>' 
   Width="290px">
  <Items>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
  </Items>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I try but this is the ERROR:
DataBinding: System.Data.DataRowView no contiene una propiedad con el nombre "Name,Type,Place"

Comment: Great, I guess this will work, but now the SelectedValue gives an error
" System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'DropD_Name' tiene un SelectedValue que no es válido porque no existe en la lista de elementos."

Comment: I modified the code. This works properly.

Comment: The final query is this: SELECT CONCAT (Name,' - ',Type,' - ',Place) AS TextColumn,Name AS Name FROM dbo.vwnames

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. But formating will be awfull.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT CONCAT(Name,' ',Type,' ',Place) AS Name FROM dbo.vwnames"
```

You can try to improve it using string leftpad or rightpad and proportional fonts, but it is out of the scope of this question. Better try something like listview or gridview.